# Upload stock images Appium iOS Simulator

Tags: python, ios, appium

My application allows for users to upload a picture of themselves. The iOS simulator comes with stock images. How would I go about using one of those stock images for the image upload?

After clicking on the element that allows for users to upload images I receive the iOS popup:

[image: iOS image upload popup]

I select "Album" but when using the Appium inspector it does not allow any access to these images, I am not able to select any (as seen in the screenshot)

[image: Screenshto of appium inspector]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if its possible to parse this screen since its already other app: **Photos app**.

With Appium you can interact only with the app that is signed same certificate as WebDriverAgent. At least its valid for real devices, but since you are not able to parse with *Appium Desktop* my guess its still the same for simulator.

You might try to use *TouchAction/tap by coordinates* (less stable, but quick way to go) or have *integrate image recognition library*, e.g. [sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/devs/system-design.html) in your code (more work, but clearly more stable) to select images in Photos app